# Concatenating two columns using SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am very new to the SQL Server world and trying my hands with a concatenation.

In column A I have data written in the format of `2015-03-28 00:00:00 000` and in column B I have data in the format of `123456789`.

When I write the code

```
SELECT CONCAT(B1,'-',A1) FROM Tbl
```

I get a result of `123456789-Mar 28 2015 12:00AM`.

What I will like to get is `123456789-2015/03/28-00:00:00`

In addition if I only want `123456789-2015/03/28` what will the code be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CONCAT` function expects and returns strings which is why the date is being formatted like so.

Use `FORMAT` or `CONVERT` functions to force your chosen format before concatenation.

```
CONCAT(B1, '-', FORMAT(A1, 'yyyy/MM/dd'))

CONCAT(B1, '-', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), A1, 111))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `FORMAT` function to format date:

```
CREATE TABLE #Tbl(B1 NVARCHAR(100), A1 DATE);

INSERT INTO #Tbl VALUES('123456789', '2015-03-28');

SELECT 
  result1 = CONCAT(B1,'-',FORMAT(A1, 'yyyy/MM/dd-HH:mm:ss'))
  ,result2 = CONCAT(B1,'-',FORMAT(A1, 'yyyy/MM/dd'))
FROM #Tbl
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/376979)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks lad2025 for the explanation and help.  It is exactly what I was looking for.